# The Triggered Send Object must contain the Triggered Send ID or the Customer Key

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I am create TriggeredSend Email following [this guide](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/send_triggeredsend_email/), but I still get this error message:

> The Triggered Send Object must contain the Triggered Send ID or the Customer Key

This is my output message:

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns2:CreateRequest xmlns:ns2="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <ns2:Options xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:CreateOptions">
            <ns2:RequestType>Synchronous</ns2:RequestType>
        </ns2:Options>
        <ns2:Objects xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:TriggeredSend">
            <ns2:CustomerKey>01698556775</ns2:CustomerKey>
            <ns2:TriggeredSendDefinition xsi:type="ns2:TriggeredSendDefinition"></ns2:TriggeredSendDefinition>
            <ns2:Subscribers xsi:type="ns2:Subscriber">
                <ns2:EmailAddress>anpm19892013@gmail.com</ns2:EmailAddress>
                <ns2:Attributes>
                    <ns2:Name>LINK_HREF_1</ns2:Name>
                    <ns2:Value>&lt;a href='httpgetwrap|http://www.exacttarget.com' alias='ET'&gt;Dynamic ET Link&lt;/a&gt;</ns2:Value>
                </ns2:Attributes>
                <ns2:SubscriberKey>12345</ns2:SubscriberKey>
            </ns2:Subscribers>
        </ns2:Objects>
    </ns2:CreateRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
```

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `TriggeredSendDefinition` object isn't set up quite right. The `CustomerKey` should be nested inside the `TriggeredSendDefinition`.

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns2:CreateRequest xmlns:ns2="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <ns2:Options xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:CreateOptions">
            <ns2:RequestType>Synchronous</ns2:RequestType>
        </ns2:Options>
        <ns2:Objects xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:TriggeredSend">
            <ns2:CustomerKey>01698556775</ns2:CustomerKey>
            <ns2:TriggeredSendDefinition xsi:type="ns2:TriggeredSendDefinition">
               <ns2:PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
               <ns2:ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
               <ns2:CustomerKey>01698556775</ns2:CustomerKey>
            </ns2:TriggeredSendDefinition>
            <ns2:Subscribers xsi:type="ns2:Subscriber">
                <ns2:EmailAddress>anpm19892013@gmail.com</ns2:EmailAddress>
                <ns2:Attributes>
                    <ns2:Name>LINK_HREF_1</ns2:Name>
                    <ns2:Value>&lt;a href='httpgetwrap|http://www.exacttarget.com' alias='ET'&gt;Dynamic ET Link&lt;/a&gt;</ns2:Value>
                </ns2:Attributes>
                <ns2:SubscriberKey>12345</ns2:SubscriberKey>
            </ns2:Subscribers>
        </ns2:Objects>
    </ns2:CreateRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
```

[Here is some sample code.](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/send_triggeredsend_email/)

Comment: Hi, you are right, i can fixed that issue

Comment: Be sure to check the question as answered.  Thanks!